# Write a method that takes a string of curly brackets and returns true if the brackets match up and false if they don’t

Tags: java

I was working on this problem in CodeHS, where I have to write a method that takes a string of curly brackets and returns true if the brackets match up and false if they don’t.

this is my coding so far, and I do not know what to do when there's same amount of left curly bracket and right curly bracket, but those just does not match like (  }}{{  ) this for an example.

```
public boolean bracketsMatch(String brackets)
{
    boolean result = true;
    int leftCtr = 0 ;  //"{";
    int rightCtr =0 ; // "}";
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<brackets.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = brackets.charAt(i);
        if ( c == '{')
        {
           leftCtr++;
        }
        if (c =='}')
        {
            rightCtr++;
        }
    }

    if (rightCtr==leftCtr)
    {
        result= true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Equality comparison `rightCtr==leftCtr` should be checked outside the for-loop.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @musefan yup, Just did it. Thank you so much

Comment: The error is that there is same amount of left curly bracket and right curly bracket, but it just does not match like }}{{ this.

Comment: @musefan yup, realized that just now and fixed it haha

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way is just to keep a single count, which you increment for an open bracket and decrement for a closed bracket. then use the following rules:

1. If the count is **ever** below 0, then it is invalid (i.e. a closing bracket that was never opened)
2. If **at the end** the count is not 0, then it is invalid (i.e. too many open brackets)

With that in mind your code would look like this:

```
public boolean bracketsMatch(String brackets)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=0; i< brackets.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = brackets.charAt(i);
        if ( c == '{')
        {
           count++;
        }
        else if (c =='}')
        {
            count--;
        }

        // Process the first rule.
        // Check if we have a negative count (i.e. close bracket without a matching opener).
        // If we have a negative then we know the string is invalid, so we can stop processing and return (false) early.
        if (count < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Process the second rule.
    // If we got this far then we know there are no invalid close brackets, so now we need to just check to make sure we didn't have too many open brackets.
    // Return true if everything matching (i.e. 0), otherwise false.
    return count == 0; 
}
```

Comment: Okay, makes sense but I do not understand how it also works for cases like }}{{ ? Thank you

Comment: Because even though it's }}{{ wouldn't that equal zero as well? since it is              -1-1+1+1 ?

Comment: @CodingBat: Yes it would equal zero... *if* we let it ever get to the end of the function. This is why we check for negative numbers on every loop. In your example, the first loop `count` will be `-1` and that means it's invalid. If we get `-1` then we exit the function early so we never end up checking the total counts, and we basically stop processing the rest of the string.

Comment: Okay, I get it now thank you so much and have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 2):

Already **Musefan** gave a brilliant answer. Here is an another implementation. Using Stack Data Structure.

```
public static boolean isBracketMatch(String str) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c == '{')
            stack.push('}');
        else if (c == '}') {
            if (!stack.empty() && stack.peek() == c)
                    stack.pop();
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
    return stack.empty();
}
```

Comment: It's nice, but mostly relevant when the program also needs to handle multiple kinds of brackets, e.g. ( { and [.

Comment: This answer was according to the OP's requirements. But implementing it for any type of brackets is not difficult. :)